# How can I loop days of the week in R

Tags: r

How can I loop days of the week in R, I tried:

```
for (day in c(Mon:Sun)){
  print(paste("hint, it's", day))
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object 'Monday' not found
Traceback:
```

I also tried:

```
# your code here
days <- c(Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun)
for(day in days)
{
 print(paste("hint, it's ", day))
}
```

Comment: Try replacing the days part with this: `days <- c('Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun')`

Comment: Try `paste("hint, it's", weekdays(as.Date(1:7, origin="1970-01-04")))`.

Comment: @jay.sf I've got: `'Hello world, it\'s  Monday''Hello world, it\'s  Tuesday''Hello world, it\'s  Wednesday''Hello world, it\'s  Thursday''Hello world, it\'s  Friday''Hello world, it\'s  Saturday''Hello world, it\'s  Sunday'` how to deal with the \ that's popping etween it and s?.

Comment: @Duck  nice!, I tried this: `days <- c("Mon", "Tues", "Wednes", "Thurs", "Fri", "Satur", "Sun")
for (day in days){
    print(paste("hint, it's ", day, "day!"))
}`, but I've got: `[1] "hint, it's  Mon day!"
[1] "hint, it's  Tues day!"
[1] "hint, it's  Wednes day!"
[1] "hint, it's  Thurs day!"
[1] "hint, it's  Fri day!"
[1] "hint, it's  Satur day!"
[1] "hint, it's  Sun day!"`, how can I remove the space between day and "day!"?

Comment: @user432797 I'm not sure, can't reproduce that, the `\\` don't show up when I run the code.

Comment: @jay.sf I'm using R kernel in jupyter notebook, can you try it please? thanks!

Comment: @user432797 I'm not using Jupyter, sorry, mate. I would try to ask a new question specifically on this topic.

Comment: @user432797 Replace the `paste` in your loop by `paste0`. It should work!

Comment: @Duck it did work, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will result in printing the list indices (Using `print`):

```
days <- c("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun")
for (day in days){
    print(paste("hint, it's ", day))
}

[1] "hint, it's  Mon"
[1] "hint, it's  Tue"
[1] "hint, it's  Wed"
[1] "hint, it's  Thu"
[1] "hint, it's  Fri"
[1] "hint, it's  Sat"
[1] "hint, it's  Sun"
```

This will remove the list indices (Using `cat`):

```
days <- c("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun")
for (day in days){
    cat(paste("hint, it's ", day, "\n"))
}

hint, it's  Mon 
hint, it's  Tue 
hint, it's  Wed 
hint, it's  Thu 
hint, it's  Fri 
hint, it's  Sat 
hint, it's  Sun
```

Comment: thanks! it is nice, but how can I remove the [1] on each line?

Comment: @user432797 Try `for (day in days) {cat(paste("hint, it's ", day, "\n"))}`.

Comment: Agreed. `cat` should do it

Comment: @jay.sf it worked! sorry that I did not this earlier, but how did R got real day value? and I really wanted to upvote every answer here, but because I'm new, it seems I can't upvote your answers, I apologize!

Comment: @user432797 You may [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), though.